# Replace multiple semicolon to single one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace

I try to remove multiple semicolon (;) replace to single semicolon  (;) in javascrpt.

code:

```
var test ="test1;;test2;;;test3;;;;test4;;;;test5;;;;;test6;;;;;;test7;;;;;;;test8;;;;;;;;test9"
test.replace(";;",";")
```

But not get proper output.(must use replace)
if any solution

I need output like :

```
test1;test2;test3;test4;test5;test6;test7;test8;test9
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three issues there:

1. When you pass a string into `replace` as the first argument, only the first occurrence is replaced. To do a global replace, you have to use a regular expression with the `g` flag.
2. If it did the whole string, you'd only replace `;;` with `;`, so if you had `;;;;` you'd end up with `;;` (each of the two being replaced). A regex also helps here, specifically `/;+/g` which means "one *or more* `;` characters, globally in the string."
3. `replace` doesn't change the string you call it on, it *returns* a new string with the changes. To remember what it does, you have to assign the result somewhere.

So:

```
test = test.replace(/;+/g, ';');
```